# Not able to read CSV file in python

Tags: python

I am trying to Import CSV file in python but I am getting following error while doing it.

```
import csv
with open('retlvl2.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        print ', '.join(row)
  **File "<ipython-input-12-82caba3702b8>", line 4
    print ', '.join(row)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax**
```

Can anyone help on this, please?

Comment: The `**File "<ipython-input-12-82caba3702b8>", line 4`, is indeed invalid syntax. It looks like something copied from an error message?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you're trying to use python2 syntax in python3.  `print` needs parentheses in python3.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Python 3 you should add parenthesis to your print declaration:

```
print(', '.join(row))
```

Comment: Thak you for delete answer :)+30

Answer (score 0):

Try with parenthesis, What is your python version???

`print (', '.join(row))`

Comment: Thanks for the input. its Python 3.6.4 32 Bits.

Comment: `but even after that, I am getting an error

with open('retlvl2.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        print (', '.join(row))
        
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-13-cd38e3cb57f8>", line 3, in <module>
    for row in spamreader:`

Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Comment: you have opened the file in 'rb' [read the file in binary] mode. Replace 'rb' with 'rt', it will work fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from your csv file. Lines can end in '\n', '\r', or '\r\n',..
You should try this

```
with open('C:\Test\example.csv', newline='') as csvfile:

with open('C:\Test\example.csv', newline='\n') as csvfile:

...
```

I am not sure but you should try.